# Find the method!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the method for how many terms are in the geometric series:

$1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \dotsm + 512$.

My thoughts:
The series is geometric with a first term of $1$, a ratio of $2$, and a tenth term of $512$. Using the formula, $S_{10} = \frac{1 (1 - 2^{10})}{1 - 2} = \frac{-1023}{-1} = 1023$. You determine that $512$ is the tenth term by solving $1(2^{x - 1})= 512$ for x.

It is obvious that there is $10$ terms in the series, so I just went ahead and solved the problem, but I would really like to know the formula for finding how many terms are in the series!

As to finding the nth term in the series, it has come to my knowledge that using the formula for geometric sum of terms is very misleading. Using logarithms is very much more useful, as demonstrated by @fleeblood and others. Why my topic is off of terms with coordinance of the website is beyond me! I added these words for hopefully they would open my material back up.

Comment: What is the formula for the terms of the series? If you know that, then the number of terms is very easy to find.

Comment: I have no idea. It show me an example for an arithmetic problem, but no formula. Basically it was this, the terms were $3$ apart so they did $3n - 1 = 89$. That doesn't stand up here, if I'm correct!

Comment: OK, so how do you know that $S_{10} = 1 \cdot \frac{1 - 2^{10}}{1 - 2}$?

Comment: From the geometric formula for sum of terms.

Comment: Then you must know that the series is a geometric series? If you do, you already have the 'formula' I asked for in my first comment.

Comment: You're wrong tho. How can 10 terms be$-1023$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44496/discussion-between-shardulc-and-william-zlacki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You determine that $512$ is the tenth term by solving $1(2^{x - 1}) = 512$ for x.

Answer (score 3):

I feel this is a little backwards and relying on memorization rather than commons sense and intuition but,

If you know the $S_{n} = \frac{1 - 2^n}{1-2} = 2^n - 1$

Then you know that the $n$ term is

$S_n - S_{n-1} = (2^n -1)-(2^{n-1} - 1) $

$= 2^n - 2^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}(2 -1) = 2^{n-1}$

So the figure out what term $512$ is you have to solve $2^{n-1} = 512$

so $n-1 = \log_2 512 = 9$

so $n = 1$

**In other words, the $n$th term is $2^{n-1}$ and the what term a number $w$ is $n = \log_2 w + 1$.**

It seems that using the sum formula to determine the terms is a little backwards.  I'd have just gone:

$S_n = 1 + 2 + 4 .... = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}$

So as $512 = 2^9$ (or in other words, $\log_2 512 = 9$) we know  that $9 = n -1$ term and so it is the 10th term.

I'd have left the sum formula out entirely.  (Especially as the sum formula is derived from the terms and not the other way around!)

Answer (score 2):

Use logarithms: $1+\,^2\!\log 512=10$

Logarithms are the inverse functions of exponentiation:

$y=f(x)=a^x\iff x=f^{-1}(y)=\,^a\!\log y$.

For inverses it holds:

$(ff^{-1})(y)=y$ and $(f^{-1}f)(x)=x$.

In your case $f(x)=2^x$ and then $f^{-1}(y)=\,^2\!\log y$

You can calculate $\displaystyle\,^2\!\log y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln 2}$.

Comment: I really don't fully understand logarithms at this point. Could you please explain?

Comment: If you will break down your answer for me!

Comment: What is the 2 infront of the log?

Comment: @WilliamZlacki This is another notation for "logarithm with base 2". Perhaps you have seen it written as $\log_2$.

Comment: Yes I have. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know that $S_n=\frac{1-2^n}{1-2}$. Now, if your question is: *"Having $S_n$, what is $n$?."* then I can say you need to use logarithms. To do this, rewrite the first equation to isolate $2^n$: $$2^n=1+S^n$$ and now apply $\log_2(\cdot)$ on both sides: $$n=\log_2{\left(1+S^n\right)}$$
You can see, if, for example, $S^n=1023$ then $n=\log_2{1024}=10$ or if $S^n=63$ then $n=\log_2{64}=6$.